# Need assistance creating oracle view of Varchar2(32767) Is JSON column with nested data, says column ambiguously defined

Tags: json, oracle, view

Objective: Create oracle view of table

```
IMP_API_RESULTS(IMP_API_RESULTS_ID Raw(16), AJ_Results_JSON Varchar2(32767) Is JSON)
```

that includes nested JSON data in column AJ_Results_JSON.

Environment: Oracle Cloud Autonomous Transaction Processing (ATP) 19c + APEX 20

Problem: Can create a view if nested data not included.  Oracle gives column ambiguously defined error when including nested data that has column names that duplicate non-nested data, specifically "id".
View works fine without nested data, but when defined with nested tags data it generates ambiguous column error:

```
Create or Replace View VW_API_Contacts
  As
  Select j.*
    From IMP_API_RESULTS d, 
        json_Table(d.AJ_Results_JSON,
        '$.contacts'
        columns (
          id,
          creator,
          created_at,
          prefix,
          first_name,
          middle_name,
          last_name,
          suffix,
          nickname,
          last_privacy_offering_date,
          nested path '$.contacts.tags[*]'
          columns ( id   Varchar2(10) path '$.contacts.tags.id', 
                    name Varchar2(50) path '$.contacts.tags.name')
          )
         ) j;
```

Comment: It seems like you know what the problem is - you have `id` in both the main and the nested `columns` clauses. Renaming one of those will remove the error... right? e.g. the nested one to `tag_id`. How would you expect any view (or table) to work with two columns with the same name?

Comment: My problem was not knowing how to do the renaming.  I did just figure that out by changing it to: nested path '$.contacts.tags[*]'
          columns ( tag_id Path '$.contacts.tags.id', name).  Now it works without erroring, but does not return data in those two columns.  the json data for the nested elements looks like: "tags":[{"name":"2593-6999","id":247509}]

Comment: Well... as a hint, what do you think the path in the second `columns` is relative to? The outer root `$`, or the result of the `nested path`?

Comment: I would expect the outer path, so I also tried: columns ( tag_id Path '$.id', name) without success (no values returned)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As established, you need a different identifier for the outer and nested columns, e.g.:

```
      columns ( tag_id Varchar2(10) path '$.contacts.tags.id', 
                name Varchar2(50) path '$.contacts.tags.name')
```

But the path in the nested part is relative to nested row, so:

```
      columns ( tag_id Varchar2(10) path '$.id', 
                name Varchar2(50) path '$.name')
```

But your `nested path` is wrong too; that is relative to `$.contacts`, so that doesn't need to include the `contacts` element again:

```
Select j.*
    From IMP_API_RESULTS d, 
        json_Table(d.AJ_Results_JSON,
        '$.contacts'
        columns (
          id,
          creator,
          created_at,
          prefix,
          first_name,
          middle_name,
          last_name,
          suffix,
          nickname,
          last_privacy_offering_date,
          nested path '$.tags[*]'
          columns ( tag_id Varchar2(10) path '$.id', 
                    name Varchar2(50) path '$.name)
          )
         ) j;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d25e3123ca4d4f3eb9023d0252a06247)

Comment: That's it!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

## that is limitation for varchar2
see following.

Connected to:
Oracle Database 19c Enterprise Edition Release 19.0.0.0.0 - Production
Version 19.3.0.0.0

SQL> create table IMP_API_RESULTS(IMP_API_RESULTS_ID Raw(16), AJ_Results_JSON Varchar2(32767) Is JSON);
create table IMP_API_RESULTS(IMP_API_RESULTS_ID Raw(16), AJ_Results_JSON Varchar2(32767) Is JSON)
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00910: specified length too long for its datatype

Comment: If you modify Max_string_Size in the database you can use varchar2 columns that are 32767.  The table is defined ok, the view is what is giving me trouble.  Also I loosely defined the table in the example as IS JSON without including the constraint check command because I was primarily interested in showing table structure the view was based on